# Bar graph graphing by y-axis rather than x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, lubridate

I've been trying to make this ggplot barchart in R using a yearmon variable (from lubridate) on the x-axis and then a numeric variable on the y-axis.

In my dataframe, I converted date to yearmon and added the yearmon values as a new column in the dataframe

```
#Make a yearmon variable for the Health dataframe
Discharge.Date <- ym(Health$Discharge.Month)
Health <- mutate(Vizient, Discharge.Date, .before = Hospital)
Health$Discharge.Date <- as.yearmon(Health$Discharge.Date, "%Y-%m")
```

Then I filtered the Health dataframe for a specific hospital. Lets call it "xyz".

```
xyz <- filter(Vizient, Hospital == "xyz")
xyz1 <- as.data.frame(xyz)
```

[image: This is the result]

Then I used this ggplot command.

```
ggplot(xyz1, aes(x=Discharge.Date, y=Cases)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + scale_x_yearmon() + xlab("Discharge Month") + ggtitle("xyz Monthly ACS Cases") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image: I got this graph here]

However, I don't understand why the bars aren't coming from the x-axis rather than the y-axis.

Interestingly, it works fine when I use x=Discharge.Month (the Date variable) instead of x=Discharge.Date (the yearmon variable)

[image: shown here]

This is all really weird because the graph was being plotted correctly when I was writing the script a year ago.

Everything is explained above. Thank you :)

Comment: Welcome to SO! From the image of your plot I would guess that your `Cases` column is a character or factor instead of a numeric. Check your data and convert to a numeric. For more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data.

Comment: OMG that worked. I love when the fix is so simple. Thanks so much!